# Choose XML transaction based off descendants with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to get a list of transactions based of a descendant. But I am having trouble getting the linq syntax correct.
My data  looks like this:

```
<Data>
    <MyTransactionXML>
           <contract>
                <contractID>1234</contractID>
                <ProductCode>ABC</ProductCode>
           </contract>
           ...
    </MyTransactionXML>
    <MyTransactionXML>
            <contract>
                <contractID>13334</contractID>
                <ProductCode>DEF</ProductCode>
           </contract>
           ...
    </MyTransactionXML>
</Data>
```

I was thinking something like this but it didn't work:

```
xdoc.Root.Descendants("MyTransactionXML")
         .Where(y => y.Descendants("ProductCode")
                      .Where(z => z.Value == "NY.E.ENG.JE.SVC.RF.VAR2.UP") == true);
```

I don't want to hard code that it is MyTransactionXML.contract.ProductCode, because if the location changes or we use similar transactions with a product code but different structure I still want to be able to get the transactions.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do? -1

Comment: Like it says in my question how do i select the specified transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Any()` instead of `Where()` when filtering transactions by product code, because predicate should return boolean value

```
from t in xdoc.Descendants("MyTransactionXML")
where t.Descendants("ProductCode").Any(c => (string)c == "DEF") // here
select t
```

Same with lambda syntax:

```
xdoc.Descendants("MyTransactionXML")
     .Where(t => t.Descendants("ProductCode").Any(c => (string)c == "DEF"))
```

---

Or you can use XPath extensions

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//MyTransactionXML[*/ProductCode='DEF']");
```

`*` wildcard matches any nodes, so you will handle changes of xml structure

Comment: Cool, I used the first method and it worked. thanks for the second way as well!